# Integer sorting using Collections, using custom class in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

For instance:

```
class A{
    public int a;
    public String b;

    public A(int a, String b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}


main(){
    List<A> list = new Arraylist<>();
    list.add(new A(5, "abc"));
    list.add(new A(1, "aee"));
    list.add(new A(3, "adf"));
    list.add(new A(6, "aad"));
    list.add(new A(2, "xx"));
}
```

Is there any way to sort this `list` in ascending order using the `integer` in `A class`. I've already tried

`Collection.sort(list)` but getting some syntax error. What I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom `Comparator` implementation:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<A>() {
    public int compare(A first, A second) {
        return Integer.compare(first.a, second.a);
    }
});
```

Comment: `return Integer.compare(first.a, second.a)` avoids unnecessary `Integer` creation.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java8 `List.sort` and a lambda expression for the Comparator you can write:

```
list.sort((a1,a2) -> a1.a - a2.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use custom `Comparator`

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<A>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(A o1, A o2) {

                if(o1.a==o2.a){
                    return 0;
                }else {
                   return o1.a>o2.a?1:-1;
                }
              }

            });
```

Comment: Your comparator doesn't isn't anti-symmetrical: it should return 0 for `o1.a == o2.a`. `Integer.compare(o1.a, o2.a)` is easier.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<A> listElements = new ArrayList<>();
    listElements.add(new A(5, "abc"));
    listElements.add(new A(1, "aee"));
    listElements.add(new A(3, "adf"));
    listElements.add(new A(6, "aad"));
    listElements.add(new A(2, "xx"));
    //Sorting
    Collections.sort(listElements, new Comparator<Pourtest.A>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(A o1, A o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.a, o2.a);
        }
    });
    //Verify
    for (A listElement : listElements) {
        System.out.println(listElement.a);
    }
```

Comment: Your comparator doesn't isn't anti-symmetrical: it should return 0 for o1.a == o2.a. Integer.compare(o1.a, o2.a) is easier.